# Error when deploying shiny app to Google Cloud Run

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, shiny

I see this error in the app service logs:

```
cannot create dir '/srv/shiny-server/app_cache', reason 'Permission denied
```

#### Docker file

```
# get shiny server and R from the rocker project
FROM rocker/shiny:4.0.5

# system libraries
# Try to only install system libraries you actually need
# Package Manager is a good resource to help discover system deps
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libssl-dev


# install R packages required
# Change the packages list to suit your needs
RUN R -e 'install.packages(c("shiny", "shinyWidgets", "shinyjs", "bslib", "firebase", "jsonlite", "httr", "purrr", "tidyr", "dplyr", "openxlsx"), \
            repos="http://cran.rstudio.com"\
          )'


# copy the app directory into the image
COPY ./shiny-app/* /srv/shiny-server/

# run app
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server"]
```

What is the meaning of this error? How can I allow permission?

Comment: An app's writable temporary space is `/tmp`. I do not know the `shiny` application, but check if you can change the directory used for caching to `/tmp`. Note: the app's writable space is a memory-mapped file system. That means you must increase the Cloud Run memory for those files. Also, Cloud Run is normally stateless. Cache files are not shared between multiple Cloud Run instances.